# "and" and "or" statements in java

Tags: java

I have a question about "and" and "or' statements in java.  Is there a way to use both of them in the same if statement?

for example:

```
if(a==max && b==0) || (a==max && c==0){
    a==0;
} else { 
     a==max;
}
```

is this legal?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: legal logically, but not syntactically.  I would add another set of parentheses: `if((a==max && b==0) || (a==max && c==0)){`

Comment: You could also just do this, and it would be less redundant: `if (a==max && ( b==0 || c==0))`

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses around the outside:

```
if((a==max && b==0) || (a==max && c==0)) {
    a = 0;
} else { 
    a = max;
}
```

Remember that `==` is a comparison and `=` is an assignment:

```
a = 5; // a is now 5.
if(a == 5) // is a equal to 5?
    // more code
```

Also as a side note, your logic can be compressed using [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra):

```
if((a == max && b == 0) || (a == max && c == 0))

is the same as:

if(a == max && (b == 0 || c == 0))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, it just corrects his code mistake

Comment: @NicholasEason yes it does, his problem was the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as many `and` or `or` statements as you want in a single if statement until you run out of memory, of course.

i.e.

```
if(a == b || b == c && d == e || d == c)
```

is completely valid. However, you mustn't forget operator precedence!

So while you read

"if a is equal to b or b is equal to c and d is equal to e or d is equal to c"

The compiler reads:

```
if(a == b || (b == c && d == e) || d == c)
```

To put this another way, lets just use true and false:

```
if(false || false &&  true || false)
```

The result: false

But *why*?

```
          //Remember how and statements work, true && false is still false
```

if(false || (false) || false)

`and` comes before `or`, just like `*` comes before `+`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what underlies all the other answers, but what nobody else has said explicitly:

A simple `if` statement looks like **if** **(** *condition* **)** *statement*

The parentheses around the *condition* are not optional.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use both of them in the same if statement?

Yes! You're totally on the right track, just missing a set of parenthesis, and a few other small mistakes!

You have the right idea. You want to use two and statements, where if either the left or the right statement is true you will assign `a=0`, otherwise `a=max`.

```
if((a==max && b==0) || (a==max && c==0)){ // Compilation error #1
     a=0; // Compilation error #2
} else { 
     a=max; // Compilation error #3
}
```

Thus if you were trying to run the code you would have 3 compiler errors:

1. Missing outer parenthesis for entire if statement
2. `a==0` should be `a=0` to assign zero to 0, instead you're checking for equality
3. `a==max` should be `a=max`, for the same reasons as 2.